# How can I start my PC even if CPU fan is not correctly placed?

Tags: cpu, fan, attachments

I was cleaning my PC and remove the dust in it and I've removed all the pieces. When I tried to replace the CPU fan, I broke 1 of the 4 mounting clip to attach it.

Now, when I tried to start my PC the red LED named +CPU is ON and I can't start even if the CPU fan works properly. How can I pass through this security?

Comment: Most likely something is not seated currently during re-assembly. It could be the CPU RAM or any Graphics card for example. Re-seat all components, recheck all cables and check again. If CPU cooler fan is not correctly oriented because of broken clip, it might not adequately cool the CPU and CPU might heat up more than normal. When I had assembled my Ryzen PC, I had to re-seat RAM 2 - 3 times before it could clear the CPU Debug LED.

Comment: Can you get a replacement fan that will mount properly?

Comment: Do not use the computer without adequate cooling for the CPU.

Comment: @patkim Ok, I've tried to replace all the components (SSD, CPU and CPU fan, all the cables) but the LED is still ON. I've tried to move the RAM to the 1st and 3rd spot but this doesn't solve the issue. I will try another attempts of replacing all the components but I think that buying a new cooler is my only solution now.

Comment: @John Yes, I will try to buy a new one because I can't solve this problem even if I tried to replace all the components once again..

Comment: @harrymc I don't want to use my computer without CPU cooling, the CPU fan is working and I just want to know if the problem is caused by the CPU fan or something else...

Comment: What if you purposely start your PC without any RAM? Does it give any beeps (Assuming speaker is attached to the mobo header)? Now this time, does it clear the CPU Debug LED and rest on RAM? Generally what Firmware knows is that CPU fan has enough RPM above a threshold. It may be blowing air elsewhere instead of the CPU Cooler. During dusting, you might have ended up blocking some contacts inside the RAM slot with dust particles.

Comment: @patkim I've just tried and the CPU LED is still ON even if I start the PC without RAM.

Comment: One more thing I suggest is to Reset CMOS and let it try to start over again. There are 2 pins on the motherboard that you need to short for 5 - 6 seconds using a metallic object like a screw driver to reset CMOS. Now try starting your system. Alternatively you can remove CMOS battery but you might need to wait for 5 - 10 minutes. So shorting mobo CLR_CMOS or CLR_RTC pins is faster.

Comment: @patkim Ok, I've shorted the 2 pins for the CMOS reset but when I tried to restart the system the CPU LED is still ON. I will try to remove the CMOS battery but I really don't have any hope at this point.

Comment: I assume all power plugs (24 Pin ATX) as well as 4 or 8 pin CPU EPS as well as any PCIe GPU if any are  plugged correctly & firmly. Above suggestions were more or less   textbook approaches. Now that they have not worked, it could be fair to assume that there's some CPU or socket issue, either faulty CPU/Bent pins, not all contacts correctly touching in CPU socket and so on. Closely inspect the CPU and the socket for any visible indicators of any damage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124030/discussion-between-bandoleras-and-patkim).

Comment: I literally tried everything imaginable to turn off that red LED. I've tried turning on without the graphics card, with only RAM, without the SSD, with another fan on the CPU, changing the 4 pin connector but it definitely stays on. So the problem must come from the CPU socket.

Answer (score 3):

The error is not a fan error, it is a CPU error. It is at best mis-seated, at worst has bent pins. You're going to have to split it again to see which… but far more carefully than last time.

At minimum, buy a new cooler.
At best you're not getting a square push with just 3 clips & it's unseating the CPU.
I get the feeling, though, you did more than break a clip - there is no mention of replacing the cooler paste, so a wild guess would be you've mis-aligned the re-assembly, even compounding the issue with dried-up old paste, pushing the CPU itself out of square.
There's also the outside chance you unseated the CPU as you tried to split the cooler off it.

I'd be seriously tempted to recommend a repair shop, before you break something else. BTW, you don't need to spilt the cooler from the CPU for a 'bit of a dust' unless you are actually doing it to replace the cooler paste.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your CPU is seated correctly in its socket, no pins bent or broken.  Next make sure any peel-off protectors or membranes attached to the CPU or the underside of the cooler have been removed.  Make sure there's a suitable amount of thermal paste on there.

Now, if you lie your PC down so that the CPU is facing up, you can place the cooler on top of it with NO CLIPS, so it's just flat on there.  It should stay in place due to gravity.
No clips is important because if you have some but not all it could pull the cooler to one side.  Flat contact is what you need.

Now you can try starting your PC, to see if it boots.  If it does, turn it off again and buy new clips or a new cooler.  If not, unfortunately the problem is with the CPU, not just the cooler.